# Soft Reference in the role of GC in java

Tags: java, jenkins, garbage-collection, g1gc, soft-references

Recently I come across this article which does the GC tuning the Jenkins which talks about this paramter : -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB

https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/11/21/gc-tuning/

I understand it prevents OOM error, Because it clears the Soft reference object when it reaches to the threshold.

1) What is this threshold (default = 1000ms in -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB) means? What does this value denotes?

2) My jenkins seems to have 80% of the softreference (observed using HProf)

3) As suggested in the above article, If I reduce this -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB flag to 10ms What will be consequence?

NOTE : We use G1GC

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) [From Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html):

> Starting with 1.3.1, softly reachable objects will remain alive for
>   some amount of time after the last time they were referenced. The
>   default value is one second of lifetime per free megabyte in the heap.
>   This value can be adjusted using the -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB flag,
>   which accepts integer values representing milliseconds. For example,
>   to change the value from one second to 2.5 seconds, use this flag:
>
> -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=2500

3) I mean, it specifically says in the article you linked to. You'll possibly free up heap space by potentially sacrificing some performance. What more can we tell you?

> If Jenkins consumes excessive old generation memory, it may help to
>   make soft references easier to flush by reducing
>   `-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB` from its default (1000) to something smaller (say 10-200). The catch is that SoftReferences are often used
>   for objects that are relatively expensive to load, such lazy-loaded
>   build records and pipeline FlowNode data

Comment: Do you mean Softreference objects are garbage collected even If its referenced by some gc root ?

Comment: @Harry Nothing is garbage collected if it's still referenced.